# getting web_socket error while running python project

Tags: python, tensorflow, websocket, libwebsockets

I getting this error while running this project https://github.com/victordibia/skyfall

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 19, in
>   
>       from utils import web_socket_client   File "C:\Users\anurag\Downloads\skyfall-master\utils\web_socket_client.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from websocket import WebSocketException, WebSocketConnectionClosedException ImportError: cannot import name
>   'WebSocketException'

Comment: Did you install the project requirements via pip install -r requirements.txt?

Comment: Please first try updating your pip version (pip install --upgrade pip), then re-run the requirements install. If that fails, install websocket-server manually by following the instructions on their documentation page https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server Manually removing requirements is never a good practice.

Comment: sir , im getting this could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server.git', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

Comment: The fix for that is to either update your pip or install the requirement manually. I gave you the resources to perform any of those actions. Did you try any of them?

Comment: yes,sir still that error...plz help me..my school project is tomorrow